# How to avoid 404 error with git instaweb?

Tags: git

I have tried running `git instaweb start` in two different repositories. In one it works fine, and indexes all the repositories in my home directory (even though run in a subdirectory). When run in another the web site simply says "404 - No projects found".

More information:

- The top-level repository directories both have the same owner and permissions.
- The "non-working" repository has an `@` sign in the directory name.

Answer (score 1):

Found a likely cause while writing the question: Cloning the repository to a directory without the `@` character in the name fixed it.